# Enabling Z value

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst

I have a polyline that when I created it I did not enable the z value. Is there away that I can enable the z value for my polyline so that I can add z values using 3D Analyst?

Answer (score 6):

I don't know of a way to enable Z values afterwards, but here's a workflow to create a new polyline with Z enabled and copy the existing fields and data over:

1) Create a new polyline feature class which stores Z values.

[image]

2) Import the existing fields from the old polyline feature class.

[image]

3) Right click the new polyline feature class in ArcCatalog and go to Load Data.

[image]

4) Select the old polyline feature class as the Input Data, and follow the rest of the Load Data wizard.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new feature class of type "Line", and check "Coordinates include Z values", continue through the options until you get to field names. Import your original lines which didn't have Z enabled.

Then, right click your new feature class, and "Load Data" from your original polyline feature class.